# How to get the least previous element filtering it by class?

Tags: jquery

I want to get the previous element that is closest to the .me element filtering it by a .a class.This script returns me undefined..Why it's returning me undefined and how do I fix this?

```
    <p class="a" id="a1">Hello Again</p>
    <div class="a" id="a2">And Again</div>
    <p  id="a3">And Again</p>
    <p class="me">And Again</p>
</div>
<script>

  alert($(".me").prev("p.a").attr("id"));

 </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`prev()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) method only looks at the immediate sibling.

Use the [`prevAll()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) method instead to consider *all* previous siblings.

```
$(".me").prevAll("p.a").attr("id")
```

The [`attr()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method will give the ID of the first matched element, which is the nearest.

If you want to be more explicit in selecting the nearest one, use the [`first()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/first/) method or the [`eq()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method.

```
$(".me").prevAll("p.a").first().attr("id")

$(".me").prevAll("p.a").eq( 0 ).attr("id")
```